# Sending last version from SVN to Tomcat6 webapp directory

Tags: java, svn, tomcat

Well, I have a SVN Server where is all my application, my doubt is very simple but i can't find any good answer in internet. I want to know if have some way to automatic "copy" the last version of SVN Trunk TO my /var/lib/tomcat6/webapp/myproject/.

So, i want to make this "copY" only when is needed, i.e: all the night i can't configure the crontab to make this copy for me.

Comment: Actually I did not get you. Do you want to checkout/import/copy your project from svn to your workspace?

Comment: What do you mean by 'only when needed?' You want a post-commit hook for SVN?

Comment: Not @KalathokiL. Imagine i have a application in production (this is in the directory /var/lib/tomcat6/webapp/myapp), and i have the updates of version in SVN repository. When everything is ready i will need to copy all the trunk directory to myapp directory, to replace with new updates.

Comment: "i will need to copy all the trunk directory to myapp directory" -- Don't you need to build the application before deploying it?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether I got your question or not. But if you want to update your workspace project from svn you can update like following:

Use svn software like: `TortoiseSVN`. Download from [Here](http://tortoisesvn.net/). And Install in your computer.
Right click selecting your project and there is option `svn...and you will find update option`
. Click **update** your project will be updated from svn.

1. If you want to copy all file form your **trunk** you can also
   **checkout** project from **svn** clicking **checkout** option which is available in `TortoiseSVN`.
2. If you are using `netbeans` ide you can also do from there.

   a: First you can **checkout** (if you want to copy all file) **STEPS :** Go to `Team --->Sub Version--->checkout`

   b: Second if you had already checked-out **STEPS:** `Select your project--->Right Click ---> Sub Version --->Update`. It will update all from svn.

Comment: Thanks anyway, i thought that have some way to automatic "deploy" the application directly from SVN to TOMCAT6